# asyncpg add listener to Pool

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to use the `NOTIFY`/`LISTEN` feature in PostgreSQL, as seen in the `asyncpg` [docs](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.connection.Connection.add_listener) we can add a listener to a `Connection` object, but not a `Pool`, I've tried the solutions shown in [this](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/283) issue, code below:

```py
def listener(*args):
    print("ANYTHING")

async def main():
    creds = {}

    async def add_listeners(conn) -> None:
        await conn.add_listener("listener_channel", listener)

    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(**creds, setup=add_listeners)
    await asyncio.sleep(10000)


asyncio.run(main())
```

And then running

```sql
NOTIFY listener_channel
```

In PgAdmin4.

However - nothing happens. How could I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so it seems that it's not working cause all of the connections are idle, I came up with this solution

```py
import asyncio
import asyncpg


class ListenerConnection(asyncpg.Connection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._listeners_futures: dict[str: list[asyncio.Future] = {}
        
    def _dummy_callback(self, channel):
        def wrapper(*args):
            if channel not in self._listeners_futures:
                return
            for fut in self._listeners_futures[channel]:
                fut.set_result(None)
            self._listeners_futures[channel].remove(fut)
        return wrapper

    async def add_one_time_listener(self, channel):
        callback = self._dummy_callback(channel)
        await self.add_listener(channel, callback)

    async def listen(self, channel):
        await self.add_one_time_listener(channel)
        future = self._loop.create_future()
        
        if channel not in self._listeners_futures:
            self._listeners_futures[channel] = []
        self._listeners_futures[channel].append(future)
  
        return await future



async def main():
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(**creds, connection_class=ListenerConnection)
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.listen("some_channel")
        print("ANYTHING")


asyncio.run(main())
```